# In Python 3.7, does the 'opcode' event from sys.settrace give any information about the bytecode itself?

Tags: python, python-3.7

So I'm playing with the [`sys.settrace`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sys.html#sys.settrace) function. In Python 3.7, a new `opcode` event is added

> `'opcode'`
>   The interpreter is about to execute a new opcode (see dis for
>   opcode details). The local trace function is called; arg is None; the
>   return value specifies the new local trace function. Per-opcode events
>   are not emitted by default: they must be explicitly requested by
>   setting `f_trace_opcodes` to True on the frame.

I was able to get those opcode events, however there seems to be no further information——I don't even know what the opcode is and what it's doing.

Does this event only brings finer granularity, without giving any extra information?

Comment: As the docs say, you need to use [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) to interpret the meaning of the opcode.

Comment: @BaileyParker I know, but it just feels strange that there's no way to dis the current event.

Comment: @BaileyParker How do you access the opcode so that you can find out what its meaning is?

Comment: @laike9m Did you ever find out how to find out what the current opcode is?

Comment: @NoctisSkytower Sadly, no.

Comment: @laike9m After doing some more research, I found out that you can get the current opcode with `frame.f_code.co_code[frame.f_lasti]`; and if you want the opcode's name, you can use `dis.opname[frame.f_code.co_code[frame.f_lasti]]` instead.

Comment: @laike9m I just realized that last comment might have answered your question. Would you like me to write up an answer for you?

Comment: @NoctisSkytower Sure, go ahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want further information, you will need to examine the `frame` argument that is passed into the tracing function. In particular, you want to look at `frame.f_lasti` to find the last instruction executed and `frame.f_code.co_code` to access that instruction. Using those two together will give you the actual opcode. If you want the mnemonic, then you will want to use `dis.opname`; but if you simply what to match it with another opcode, then you can use `dis.opmap` instead. The following example is contrived, but it demonstrates some of what is possible using the hints just provided:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import dis
import sys


def main():
    dis.dis(add)
    sys.settrace(get_trace(False, get_callback(celebrate)))
    total = add(1, 2)
    print(f'total = {total}')
    sys.settrace(None)
    total = add(3, 4)
    print(f'total = {total}')
    print('Done')


def get_trace(trace_lines=True, opcode_callback=None):
    trace_opcodes = callable(opcode_callback)

    # noinspection PyUnusedLocal
    def trace(frame, event, arg):
        frame.f_trace_lines = trace_lines
        frame.f_trace_opcodes = trace_opcodes
        if trace_opcodes and event == 'opcode':
            opcode = frame.f_code.co_code[frame.f_lasti]
            opname = dis.opname[opcode]
            opcode_callback(frame, opcode, opname)
        return trace

    return trace


def get_callback(return_handler=None):
    handle_return = callable(return_handler)

    def echo_opcode(frame, opcode, opname):
        print(f'# {opname} ({opcode}) #')
        if handle_return and opcode == dis.opmap['RETURN_VALUE']:
            return_handler(frame)

    return echo_opcode


# noinspection PyUnusedLocal
def celebrate(frame):
    print('/-------------------\\')
    print('| We are returning! |')
    print('\\-------------------/')


def add(a, b):
    return a + b


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks Noctis. I get the idea, but probably you can simplify the snippet a bit? BTW when run, it gave the error `AttributeError: 'frame' object has no attribute 'f_trace_lines'`.

Comment: @laike9m You need the latest version of Python for the example. If you want to boil the program down to its simplest form, focus on these lines: `frame.f_trace_opcodes = trace_opcodes`; `opcode = frame.f_code.co_code[frame.f_lasti]`; `opname = dis.opname[opcode]`; and `if handle_return and opcode == dis.opmap['RETURN_VALUE']:`.

Comment: @laike9m You might also want to look at [Are there events that should be explicitly tracked or ignored?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56139425/216356) to see a practical use being developed from looking at opcodes.