# Are there events that should be explicitly tracked or ignored?

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

While doing research to solve [How to automatically re-raise exception after handlers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56084252/216356), an exception class was developed with the capability of automatically throwing itself again after it has been handled (inspired by the `ThreadAbortException` in C#). After a lot of trial and error, the class has been demonstrated to work in the simplest of cases. My concern is that there may be unnecessary overhead if an exception handler calls a function or an exception handler has its own `try` and handler blocks in it.

The class and its test so far is this:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import dis
import inspect
import sys


def main():
    try:
        raise SpecialError
    except SpecialError as error:
        print(f'{error!r} was caught!')
        # error.reset()
    print('You should not see this!')


class SpecialError(BaseException):
    DEBUG = False
    THROW = {dis.opmap['END_FINALLY'], dis.opmap['POP_EXCEPT']}

    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.__stack = []
        frame = inspect.currentframe()
        while frame:
            self.__stack.append((frame, frame.f_trace))
            frame.f_trace = self.__trace
            frame = frame.f_back
        self.__saved = sys.gettrace()
        sys.settrace(self.__trace)

    def __trace(self, frame, event, arg):
        frame.f_trace_lines = False
        frame.f_trace_opcodes = True
        if event == 'opcode':
            op = frame.f_code.co_code[frame.f_lasti]
            if self.DEBUG:
                print(dis.opname[op])
            if op in self.THROW:
                raise self
        return self.__trace

    def reset(self):
        sys.settrace(self.__saved)
        for frame, trace in self.__stack:
            frame.f_trace = trace


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Are there any events where tracing should be disabled, and are there any opcodes that should be recorded to a stack and popped off to detect when the exception should truly raise itself again (after the end of handler blocks it was caught in)?